# Concatenate strings with quotes and commas in r

Tags: r, string, string-concatenation

I got stuck with the following problem.

I have to download a file daily that looks like a matrix. One of the columns is in the format:
9766 JP  6367 JP 9983 JP 3407 JP 8309 JP and so on. The class of the column is factor.

I need to transform this column in this format:

"9766 JP", "6367 JP", "9983 JP", "3407 JP", "8309 JP"

I tried many possible solutions suggested on this website but none seems to work for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is downvoted because it is not clear what your source data looks like, or what it exactly is, what you want to achieve.

Maybe this example will help

```
library(stringr)

s <- "9766 JP 6367 JP 9983 JP 3407 JP 8309 JP"

v <- str_extract_all(s, '[0-9]{4} [A-Z]{2}')[[1]]

r <- paste0(v, collapse='","', sep="")

sq <- paste0("'",paste0(v, sep="", collapse="','"),"'")
```

results:

```
> v
[1] "9766 JP" "6367 JP" "9983 JP" "3407 JP" "8309 JP"
> r
[1] "9766 JP\",\"6367 JP\",\"9983 JP\",\"3407 JP\",\"8309 JP"
> sq
[1] "'9766 JP','6367 JP','9983 JP','3407 JP','8309 JP'"
```

Comment: Thank you but this does not solve my problem. Your r string has backslashes at the end of each JP character, while I'm looking for your solution without backslashes, i.e. "9766 JP", "6367 JP", etc.

Comment: The quotes need to be escaped in a string. Can you explain how you intend to use the string, so I can adjust to your needs?

Comment: They are characters that I read from a file and have to format "9766 JP", "6367 JP", etc. to query data from the Internet. The commas are essential as they make the run much faster. Thank you.

Comment: So using the string with escaped quotes will work if you run the query from R. If you are using copy paste to manually create a query, than you could just as well use replace in a basic text editor. Or use single quotes if that is also possible (see adjusted answer).